# TFS alert when a related task is closed

Tags: tfs, alert

I'm using TFS for task tracking in a team of ~40 people. We create Backlog Items with child Tasks. I'd like to implement some kind of automatic notifications or alerts when Tasks under a Backlog Item is closed.

For example, we have a Backlog Item like "Build a Cart", with a few child tasks:

- Server - Build a Cart (Assigned to Dev1)
- Client - Build a Cart (Assigned to Dev2)
- Content - Add content to the Cart (Assigned to Des1)
- QA - Test the Cart (Assigned to QA1)

When the first task "Server - Build a Cart" is closed, I'd like to make sure all other members (Dev2, Des1, and QA1) are alerted somehow. Some people are in different geographic locations, so automating the notification is what I'm looking for.

Is there some kind of plugin or way I can configure things to automate more alerts or notifications?

Comment: There's a robust notification system already built in. What's insufficient about that? Did you start by typing the phrase "tfs notifications" into your search engine of choice? I just did that and see numerous resources.

Comment: I'm trying to configure the notifications based on the status of another task that's linked (like a parent, child, predecessor, etc), and I can't find a way to set notifications like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that it cannot be achieved by the default TFS notification system since you need to filter the parent work items. And there isn't any plugin for this as far as I know. I would recommend you to create a service hook event for work item changed event and then create a web service to listen the event and send out email notifications base on your request.